# ${form.test} prints "var", but ${form.test== 'var'} is always false

Tags: jsp, jstl, el

when I tried to print a value in JSP, it's printing the value which is named **"var"** but when I tried to use the same value in a if condition it doesn't seem to be working. Please somebody help me...:(:(

```
<c:out value="${form.test}" /> /* for printing and it's printing "var"*/
<c:if test="${form.test== 'var'}"> /* for if condition which is not working */
```

Answer (score 0):

It should work fine, assuming that those doublequotes are not part of the value (i.e. you're seeing `var`, not `"var"`). Perhaps there's some dangling whitespace around the value?

You could debug the one and other the following ways:

```
<pre>|<c:out value="${form.test}" />|</pre> <!-- Should print |var| -->
```

and

```
<c:out value="${fn:length(form.test)}" /> <!-- Should print 3 -->
```

If it is indeed the whitespace and you cannot trim it in the servlet/SQL end, consider using `fn:trim()`:

```
<c:if test="${fn:trim(form.test) == 'var'}">
```

The [JSTL functions](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/5/jstl/1.1/docs/tlddocs/fn/tld-summary.html) taglibrary is by the way available by the following taglib declaration:

```
<%@ taglib prefix="fn" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/functions" %>
```

Comment: You need to be more specific about the concrete problem in order to be able to help you. What does it print? What does the length say? Do you in any way understand what I'm trying to explain as to debugging the problem?

Comment: The cOut is working fine and what ever its printing i am giving the same value in cIf and it doesn't work :(

Comment: Then `${form.test}` does not return an instance of `String`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
<c:if test="${form.test eq 'var'}">
```

Comment: Can you explain in detail why this would ever make any difference? Aren't you confusing with the fact that `<` and `>` cannot be used in JSPX becaue it are predefinied XML entities? The `==` and `eq` should work equally fine, regardless of the view technology.

Comment: I am not sure why this is happening. when i tried to print its working but when i tried to give the same value in a if statement its not working, its kinda strange but that's what happening :(